# http to https redirect fails

Tags: nginx

I can't seem to get http redirection to work. 
Any idea why? 
I always get

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

I tried these server blocks:

```
server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    server.com;
  rewrite        ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80 ;
  server_name server.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name;
}
```

As requested here is the 443 part
443 server block

```
     server {
     listen 443 ;

    root /folder/;
    index index.html index.htm;
    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name server.com;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;


            set $cors '';
            if ($http_origin ~* 'https?://(localhost|www\.server\.com|www\.server.\.com)') {
            set $cors 'true'; }
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;

     }
     }
```

Comment: How is the config for the server on port 443?

Comment: @StephenKing - I've added the 443 part

Comment: would you mind fixing the indentations to make it at least a bit readable? I've corrected your initial post, please do the rest on your own.

Comment: @StephenKing , I'm sorry (-: I really tried ,but the site's editor gave me grief..
i'll try again..

Answer (score 0):

In your case, nginx is listening to port 443 and expecting plain-text connections there. At least, this is what I see from the configuration (confusing is that the message says the contrary fact).

```
server {
  listen 443;
```

only specifies the port, but not the protocol. Instead, the following configuration tells nginx to expect HTTPS / TLS (previously *SSL*) connections:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
```

Comment: sadly, that's not working for me.
Still getting the same error. (restarted, used different browser, private window etc..)

Comment: Then I assume your config has some directives at other places as well. Given the chaos you've pasted here, I suggest to delete everything and start from scratch..

Comment: Thanks. I do appreciate your assistance!